# PhoneGap/Cordova device not ready

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Just build my first PhoneGap/Cordova app, using the PhoneGap iOS lib in Xcode. It all works fine, the basic "HelloWorld" app works in the iOS simulator ("Device is ready").

When I upload the created WWW directory including cordova-2.1.0.js to my webserver and try to open the app in Safari on my iPhone, it keeps saying "Connecting to device". Any idea how to get this to work / why this basic build isn't working?

Link: http://robinhq.nl/projects/cordova

Hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing PhoneGap / Cordova in a browser, use Ripple (Chrome). More info: http://emulate.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap is an application container technology that allows you to create natively-installed applications for mobile devices using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Phonegap cordova-2.1.0.js only works on iPhone app. It doesn't support on Safari Browser(IPhone).

Comment: So, I can't use the PhoneGap API (cordova-2.1.0.js) to upload files from the camera roll in a HTML5 web app?

Comment: Yes, You can't use PhoneGap API (cordova-2.1.0.js) in Web. You can only use this as Mobile App.